# Table view controller with static cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, tableview

i have a problem with my application,so when i put this code in InfoViewController and i run the application,the view appears to be empty.I have a table view setted to static cells,3 sections,style grouped with header for every section,the first cell contain a text field that i have used as a search field with google,and a search button,the second and the third contains a label.I have connected all the text field button and labels in the storyboard file,and the delegate in file’s owner.Should I Implement any other method?
Thanks for the advice.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *googleSearchTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label2;

-(IBAction)googleSearch;

@end





#import "InfoViewController.h"

@end

@implementation InfoViewController

@synthesize googleSearchTextField;
@synthesize searchButton;
@synthesize Label1;
@synthesize Label2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.Label1.text = @“Label1”;
self.Label2.text = @“Label2”;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(IBAction)googleSearch
{
NSString *searchString=googleSearchTextField.text;
NSString *urlAdress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",         
searchString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress]];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your tableViewDelegate methods and TableViewDataSource methods

Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: Also for static cells?